# How to use ExtJS to search through "JSON" grid data on demand?

Tags: json, search, extjs, grid, extjs4

Lets say that grid uses JSON to display data, but what i need is to display data only when some parameters given to search, ID or name. There is a live search grid example, but what i need is a simple search JSON for Id or name. Grid not showing anything unless some parameters are provided, this is because of a large database.

I tried this:

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        text:'Traži',
        width:80,
        margin: '14 10 5 10',
        handler:function(){

            myStore.filter('naziv', Ext.getCmp("textFieldNaziv").getValue());

}
```

but works only when grid already populated..., with autoLoad:false, no result. Which means that it doesnt "search" but only cuts down what has already displayed....??????

How to somehow say that when it "filters" it starts from top, filtering whole JSON, not only the one being displayed at the moment!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text:'Search',
    handler:function(){

        store.clearFilter();
        var searchValue = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId").getValue();
        store.load().filter('jsonGridFieldName', searchValue);

    }                   

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is all your JSON data in a `Ext.data.Store`? If so, you can use the [`filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method to filter the data in the Grid.

It's good to note that you will probably get a quicker response over on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/).

Comment: Hey! Some of us have a small amount of ext knowledge and can't get rep on those forums ;)

Comment: @rdougan - Thank you for quick response, yes I am using Ext.data.Store. My database is large, so what i need is to give some parameter into textField and the to "filter" through JSON, with a result. Do you have any example of this?

Comment: @Jonas - I use both, but there is more chances that i will get an answer here, rather then Sencha forum. Also, without premium account my chances are even smaller... ;-)

Comment: a) Please give us some time to reply; I need my sleep. b) I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. Can you try and explain again.

Comment: @rdougan sorry for rushing, different time zone... ;-). I got the answer myself, but thank anyway... cheers